# Laravel AJAX call response is redirect to login page

Tags: ajax, laravel, redirect, authentication, response

I'm using AJAX. I call the server which calls an API and gets its response. I try to return the response in JSON to the client. But my Laravel has Middleware that checks token is valid. And when it's invalid, it'll redirect to login page. So the response I return is not JSON from API call but is the HTML of the redirected login page. I don't know what to do about this. One, the response is not the expected JSON and two, how do I keep the mechanism of redirecting to login page when the situation is an AJAX call and not the usual going from one page to the next.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you used middleware groups? How you routes are made? Can you provide some code?

Check this documentation [middleware groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-groups) just to see if this is what you re trying to achieve

Comment: Are you sure your ajax is sending the csrf token? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: @Marcus I test with invalid token deliberately to see what I need to do when token is invalid. Is that the question?